# Android : speak failed : not bound to tts engine

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I have a simple app that is able to speak.

The things is I got this error in logcat:

```
TextToSpeech Sucessfully bound to com.ivona.tts
TextToSpeech speak failed : not bound to TTS engine
```

I add nothing particular in the Android manifest, do have to ?

Code

```
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener;
import android.util.Log;

public class Main extends Activity implements OnInitListener{

TextToSpeech tts;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);

    tts.speak("Hello World", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);       
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    MyTTS.release();
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        tts.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault());
    } else {
        Log.e("TTS", "Initialization failed");
    }

}

}
```

I don't know why this error occurs.
Can anyone help me?
Thank in advance

Edit : I don't want put the speak method Inside the onInit method. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 2):

You can only let the engine speak, after onInit is done, so do following in onInit():

```
   if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
     tts.speak("Hello World", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);      

   }
```